Ansible, lxd error when installing XRoad: Attribute Error: NoneType has no attribute "items" lead to lxd_container.py
I was trying to install XRoad using ansible and LXD with these steps:
Sudo snap install lxd
lxd init
$ sudo apt update $ sudo apt install software-properties-common $ sudo add-apt-repository --yes --update ppa:ansible/ansible $ sudo apt install ansible ansible-playbook hosts -i hosts/lxd_hosts.txt xroad_init.yml
I got this error: Attribute Error: NoneType has no attribute "items" leading to lxd_container.py
ansible-loop-var item: xroad-lxd-cs
Localhost ok=1 failed=1
First time i was doing nearly exact same steps i didnt get any error. Now i tried installing Xroad on a different VM (Ubuntu), i got this error.
Im using ubuntu 22.04
Thanks for any help
I tried:
Reinstalling lxd, ansible (to different versions)
Installing python 3.12
Apt update + upgrade
Change from Bridged to NAT
Reinstalling Ubuntu
Images of error:
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here

line 99, in _ansiballz_main invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
File "/home/vboxuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1728036128.1841958-3528-12931979 1180256/Ansiballz_lxd_container.py", line 47, in invoke_module runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.community.general.plugins.mod
ules.lxd_container', init_globals-dict(_module_fqn='ansible_collections.communit y.general.plugins.modules.lxd_container', _modlib_path=modlib_path), File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 224, in run_module return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec) File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
File "/tmp/ansible_lxd_container_payload_g1eotpsb/ansible_lxd_container_payloa d.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/lxd_container.py", l ine 901, in <module>

This was the main error:
ansible_collections/community/general/

Do this was all that needed:
ansible-galaxy collection install community.general -f

